# NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element with id / Works fine in FireFox and Chrome but not in IE

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the following code in Eclipse and the code works fine in both FireFox and Chrome (obviously I do not call on the IE webdriver in those test cases) but not in IE10, The code fails on the assertTrue section. So the code below opens a IE browser window, opens the requested URL, fills both Username and Password and clicks the OK button. Login is succesfull and I want to confirm that I am logged in as the user whose username and password I used.

```
public void test3() throws Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "browsers\\IEDriverServer.exe");

/** Test: Start Browser*/
driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

/** Test: Login is possible*/
driver.get ("http://URL/");
driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys("testname");
driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("Welcome01");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='']")).click();

/** Test: logged in as user confirmation*/
assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("dvPageOptions")).getText().contains("testname"));

driver.quit();
```

This throws an error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element
>   with id == dvPageOptions (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 274 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
>   System info: host: 'BA91-CNU21923BJ', ip: '10.55.17.73', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_31' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver

This is part of the source of the page

```
    < div id="dvPageOptions" style='display:inline;position:absolute;right:10px'>
logged in as: testname</div >
```

As you can see, the id and the content I'm looking to assert is in the source.

Additional info:
I'm using IE10 and Security settings are all correct (protected mode enabled for all zones)

Comment: Seems like there's an issue with IE10 browser. Did you try it in IE11? Also does the `dvPageOptions` div load a bit late in IE browser which you can test manually and see?

Comment: WebPages may differ in behaviour between various browsers. For example, the URL you are navigating to may open differently in the InternetExplorer.

You may try fetching the driver.getPageSource() and check whether an element with id = 'dvPageOptions' is actually present in the Internet Explorer Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Girish Sortur! As you mentioned the id loads a bit late so I decided to throw in a Wait action (see below). Now it works fine!

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("GoTo")));
assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("dvPageOptions")).getText().contains("testname"));
```